# web2py: how to customize add.edit forms in SQLFORM.smartgrid?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, web2py

I have data model with one parent and two child tables. I want to change custom add/edit forms based on input type text entry fields to have:
- pull down menus (made with SELECT/OPTION elements) with predefined elements,
- checkboxes.

The main page is SQLFORM.smartgrid with references to children (which I want to have several custom add/edit forms).

The URL's for change are for example:

```
http://host.com:8000/First/default/index/recipe/edit/recipe/4 (parent table)
http://host.com:8000/First/default/index/recipe/rule.recipe_id/4/new/rule (child table)
```

What should I do to change default views of SQLFORM.smartgrid "Add record" and "Edit" action buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the form widgets used for particular fields, you do not have to customize the create/update forms directly. Instead, you can just specify the appropriate validators and custom widgets:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('field1', requires=IS_IN_SET(['a', 'b', 'c'])),
    Field('field2', requires=IS_IN_SET(['x', 'y', 'z'], multiple=True),
          widget=SQLFORM.widgets.checkboxes.widget))
```

The `IS_IN_SET` validator will automatically produce a drop-down element for field1. The default for field2 would be a multi-select box, but the "widget" argument changes it to checkboxes.

If you still need to do some form customization, though, you can do something like this in the view:

```
{{if ('new' in request.args) or ('edit' in request.args):}}
    [custom form code goes here]
{{pass}}
```